# Filling up cell only if certain cell is already filled

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to do it using data validation, but I would like to add an argument.

I want the data validation formula to run only if "A109" = "test1" or "test2".

I tried this below, but it's not giving me what I want. The data validation formula is running no matter what.

```
Sub Macro2()

If Range("A109").Value = "Test1" Or "Test2" Then

    Range("B111").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK(B109))"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "ATTENTION!"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = _
        "Vous ne pouvez faire la remise en service tant que vous n'avez pas approuvé le ""...."" ou ""...."" à la cellule B109."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Sheets("Grille").Select
Else
    Stop

    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling this code?  From an event handler, or from a button, etc?  When does it run?

Comment: it's in a module... No button or event handler...

Comment: So when / how does it run?  Is this a one-time setup code?  Did you want to incorporate the A109 check into the validation formula?

Comment: it runs as soon as I type something in the cell `B111`. And yes, I want to add the A109 check into the validation formula!